# Error collation en phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, mariadb

Tengo la siguiente configuración:

- Servidor: Localhost via UNIX socket
- Tipo de servidor: MariaDB
- Conexión del servidor: No se está utilizando SSL Documentación
- Versión del servidor: 10.5.15-MariaDB-0+deb11u1 - Debian 11
- Versión del protocolo: 10
- Usuario: xxx@localhost
- Conjunto de caracteres del servidor: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8mb4)

Es un sistema nuevo. Cuanto creo una base de datos e intento activar la pestaña "privilegios" de phpmyadmin, me origina el siguiente error:

> #1267 - Ilegal mezcla de collations (utf8mb4_general_ci,COERCIBLE) y (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE) para operación '<>'

La base de datos está vacía ya que no puedo incluirle un usuario. Alguna idea de cómo corregir este error?.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Asumo que el phpMyAdmin lo instalaste por aparte o cómo lo instalaste? Revisa que la configuración de phpMyAdmin coincida con el charset que indicas. Lo otro: valida que el charset de la BD y el de las tablas que crea phpMyAdmin sea el mismo. Por ahí va el lío

Comment: Se instaló vía repositorios de Debian

Comment: La tabla está vacía